# Appropriate model structure for recording history of values

Tags: django

I can't work out what the appropriate model structure should be for this problem (simplified version to make explanation easier)

The goal is:

- a Person model with required fields
- When adding a person, you can optionally put in initial values for weight and height (one entry for each, default to 0)
- When values for height and/or weight are updated, the previous value is stored some where so the history can be viewed

I know I can have a separate model for height and for weight, linking them to Person by ForeignKey but it makes the admin presentation confusing and dis-jointed by allowing multiple entries at a time.

Alternatively, can I have height and weight as fields in Person (benefit of having clean list_view and inclusion of these fields in fieldsets), and when there is any update store the previous value into a different model? This model can then be listed to show some one's history of values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ForeignKeys to height and weight models, then add a property to access that field

```
class Person(model)
    name = CharField()

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self.weighthistory.latest().value


class Weight(model):
    value = IntegerField()
    date = DateTimeField()
    person = ForeignKey(Person, related_name="weighthistory")

class Height(model)
    value = IntegerField()
    date = DateTimeField()
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
```

Answer (score 0):

[django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/) provides this functionality. At each `save()` of your model, a history is saved with changed values and you can roll back to any previous version, in addition to listing all changes.

It does not require changing of your models, and even comes with an admin integration with a custom admin class.

A [low level API](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Low-level-API) provides more functionality.